# How to set monaco's font style?

Tags: monaco-editor, italic, font-style

I need to display the words in italic within the editor. How can I do that? I didn't find how to set this in the [`IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions.html) options when passing it to [`create`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#create) only how to specify that with [`defineTheme()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#defineTheme) like that:

```
monaco.editor.defineTheme('placeHolderTheme', {
    base: 'vs-dark',
    inherit: false,
    rules: [
        
        { 
            token: 'my-token',
            foreground: '#311b92',
            fontStyle: 'italic' 
        },
    colors: {
        "editor.background": "#2B2B2B",
        'editor.foreground': '#FFFFFF',
    }
});
```

but I do need to set the whole text at once. How can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font styles can only be set for syntax tokens in the editor. If you want to set a style for all tokens then define a token with empty match and set it there: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-tokens-and-colors.

```js
monaco.editor.defineTheme('myCustomTheme', {
    base: 'vs', // can also be vs-dark or hc-black
    inherit: true, // can also be false to completely replace the builtin rules
    rules: [
        { token: '', fontStyle: 'italic' },
        { token: 'comment', foreground: 'ffa500', fontStyle: 'italic underline' },
        { token: 'comment.js', foreground: '008800', fontStyle: 'bold' },
        { token: 'comment.css', foreground: '0000ff' } // will inherit fontStyle from `comment` above
    ],
    colors: {
        'editor.foreground': '#000000'
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm using monaco within a reactl application. How do I set to use italic style for example? i did found font family size, etc but not style

Comment: Your reference to the creation options somehow confused me. See m updated answer.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. I did found about it inhering styles but didn't how to do that with all tokens